# Adding the -O2 option when cross-compiling causes the unwind backtrace to fail

Tags: c, arm, cross-compiling, libgcc

Add `-funwind-tables` when cross-compiling, you can successfully unwind backtrace through the interface(`_Unwind_Backtrace and _Unwind_VRS_Get`) in the libgcc library.
But when I added the -O2 option at cross-compiling time, unwind backtrace would fail. I pass `-Q -O2 --help=optimizers` print out the optimization and testing, but the results and -O2 is different, very strange,

Comment: Did you look and see what `-O2` actually does?  What the entire set of optimization options it enables?  And what those options do?

Comment: I use  `-Q -O2 -help=optimizers` lists the O2 optimized option,unwind related programming optimization have been tested, the strange thing is not found abnormal optimization options

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us which ARM architecture you are building for - but assuming it's a 32-bit architecture, enabling [`-O2` has also enabled `-fomit-frame-pointer`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) (§ `-fomit-frame-pointer`)

### The frame-pointer

The frame pointer contains the base of the current function's stack frame (and with the knowledge that the caller's frame pointer is stored on the stack, a linked list of all stack frames in the call-tree).  It's usually described as `fp` in documentation - a synonym for `r11`.

### Omitting the frame-pointer

The ARM register file is small at 16 registers - one of which is the program counter. 
The frame pointer is one of the 15 that remains and is used only for debugging and diagnostics - specifically to provide stack walk-backs and symbolic debugging.

`-fomit-frame-pointer` tells the compiler to not maintain a frame pointer, thus liberating the `r11` for other uses, and potentially avoiding spill of variables to the stack from registers.  It also saves 4 bytes per stack-frame of stack storage and a store and load to the stack.

Naturally, if `fp` is used as general purpose register, its contents are undefined and walk-backs won't work.

You probably want to reenable the frame pointer with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` for your own sanity.

Comment: The device is a 32bit armv7 architecture, and when I cross-compiled I chose the `-fomit-frame-pointer` and `-funwind-tables` options, and although there was no stack frame, the stack backtrace was OK. When I added `-O2` and `-funwind-tables`, I could no longer do stack backtracking, which I didn't think was relevant. I have checked relevant information, the unwind way stack backtrace of ARM architecture is mainly carried out through`.ARM.exidx` section, I suspect that `-O2` option has affected `.ARM.exidx` section，

Comment: unwind-tables are used for C++ exception handling.  In `-O0` the compiler isn't trying very hard or at all?) to avoid spilling registers - so `r11` is unlikely to get used as a general purpose register and will at least contain something - even it's a calling function's frame-pointer.

Comment: what's meaning？

Comment: I think O2 may have optimized some registers, causing the stack backtrace to fail，but I can't find the relevant optimization options

Comment: Many optimisations have the potential to make temporary variables in programs invisible to the debugger - possibly because they are never computed at all - or are computed as part of a bigger operation or as a side-effect. 

I just did an experiment with CompilerExplorer - https://godbolt.org/z/wJbRpk - I tried to build a function which would result in use of the frame pointer - it was surprisingly difficult.   `-fomit-frame-pointer` definitely inhibited it being written to the stack-frame.

Comment: In addition to the above methods, do you know any other methods of process stack tracing？